# Multiple submit buttons on CakePHP form causes black-hole

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a form in my CakePHP with two submit buttons like so:

```
<div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" name="preview" class="btn btn-large">Preview</button>
    <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-large">Save</button>
</div>
```

However because I've given them both names it returns with an error that the request has been black-holed due to the security restrictions.

How do I get around this? As I want to do different things in the controller dependant on which button was used to submit the form.

Comment: is there a compelling reason for both to be submits?  why can't use call preview a type=button instead?

Comment: Because type button won't submit the form.

Comment: You can use `js`, is that an option?

Comment: well if cakephp has issue with you having two submits, why don't you semantically call one a button but use JS to submit it?

Comment: What if I add fake Schema to the Model?

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you give them both the same name but different values:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Preview" />
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you do this instead?

```
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="button" name="preview" class="btn btn-large">Preview</button>
        <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-large">Save</button>
    </div>

$(function() {
     $(".btn.btn-large").on("click", function(){
           $( "#yourForm" ).submit();
     }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this works:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->submit('Save and Preview', array('div'=>false, 'name'=>'submit', 'value'=>'preview')); 
echo $this->Form->submit('Publish Post', array('div'=>false, 'name'=>'submit', 'value'=>'publish')); 
?>
```